# Is the file name of DELPHI's tImage.picture.loadFromFile stored somewhere?

Tags: image, delphi

I load a picture using

```
myImage.picture.LoadFromFile('myimage.jpg');
```

It can contain either an "empty avatar" or a "real picture", so it is always "full", I cannot test for NIL and/or .empty

I would like to know if there is a way to do something like

```
if (myImage.picture.filename = 'empty.jpg') then 
  DO SOMETHING
else
  DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

Sure, I can create a global variable and/or (wow) derive a new tImage class adding that property but I guess it's a bit too much.

Thank you

Comment: You could compare the loaded image with the empty image.

Comment: Uhm, the reason is to avoid loading the image again. In order to compare them, I have to reload the image again ;)

Comment: You need to remember more than the file name. You also need to remember a time stamp or perhaps a file hash.

Comment: ZioBit, you could have the empty image stored in a `TImageList` or any container which loads at startup.

Comment: "Use the Source, Luke" ! Just open the file and read the sources of the `myImage.picture.LoadFromFile(...)` procedure  then say if that procedure does or does not save the variable anywhere. Also, put the breakpoint in that line, open Project Properties, mark the "Debug .DCUs" check box and trace into the said procedure's internals and, again, see with your own eyes if the filename variable is saved anywhere or not

Comment: Why not simply check the color of few pixels of the lodaded image to see if it is the same as the color of those pixels would be if avatar picture would be loaded?

Answer (score 4):

No record is kept of where the image originated. You would need to track this.

You certainly don't need to use a global variable to track this. You would typically use a variable at the same scope as the image control.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I am sorry, I call "global" any variable of the unit. Since the image belongs to the form, I would have to use a "global" variable, meaning one declared on the "var" section of the form.

Comment: Global means at unit scope. What you describe is an instance variable.

Comment: I think what you need is a variable that is declared in the private section of the form class.

Comment: @GuidoG that's what the answer says

Comment: I know but I had the impression from the op's comment on your answer that he did not understood this correct

Answer (score 2):

This is no property that keeps track of the image filename. If you simply need to know whether it's an avatar image or a specified image, you could use the **Tag property**. myImage.Tag = 0 for empty, myImage.Tag = 1 for specified.

If the project requires the filename, you could store that as a variable, or if it's a Firemonkey project, use the TagString property.

If the project is VCL, you could use the Hint property to store the filename if you're not using the Hint property for an actual hint (set ShowHint to false so the user doesn't see it).

Comment: Good idea, I always forget about those tags, that can be used for general purpose storage :)